# problem with script creating table via if clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We are trying to build a script which automatically checks if a table is already created and if so the script should end. If the table is not created the script should create it.

```
    case 
    if select count(*) from ALL_TAB_COLS where table_name = 'GPS_TRACKER_DATA' = 0 then
       create table AZUBI.GPS_TRACKER_DATA as select * from KAKATEL.GPS_POSITION
    else end
```

this is the error we are getting

```
    Error starting at line : 3 in command -
    create table FEZ.GPS_TRACKER_DATA as select * from KAKATEL.GPS_POSITION
    else END
    Error report -
    ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be done in PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
    V_CNT   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    INTO V_CNT
    FROM
        ALL_TABLES -- USE ALL_TABLES 
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = 'GPS_TRACKER_DATA'
        AND OWNER = 'AZUBI'; -- ADDED OWNER CONDITION

    IF V_CNT = 0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table AZUBI.GPS_TRACKER_DATA as 
                           select * from KAKATEL.GPS_POSITION';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hey, if I wanted to add a PK for one column how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to query the data dictionary to see if the table exists; just try to create the table using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and catch the exception if it already exists.

```sql
DECLARE
  ALREADY_EXISTS EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( ALREADY_EXISTS, -955 );
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM existing_table';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ALREADY_EXISTS THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=42b1b46f62934df0aa15e7d3c06b40c3)*

Answer (score 0):

One option would be :

```
declare
  v_cnt pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into v_cnt
    from ALL_TAB_COLS
   where table_name = 'GPS_TRACKER_DATA';
  if v_cnt = 0 then
    execute immediate 'create table AZUBI.GPS_TRACKER_DATA as 
                       select * from KAKATEL.GPS_POSITION';
  end if;
end;
/
```

- `execute immediate` is needed for a `DDL` statement within a `PL/SQL`
  block.
- that select statement returns a non-negative(and even non-null)
  integer for any case.

You can replace `if..then..end if` by `case..when then..end case`, also :

```
declare
  v_cnt pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into v_cnt
    from ALL_TAB_COLS 
   where table_name = 'GPS_TRACKER_DATA';
  case
    when v_cnt = 0 then
      execute immediate 'create table AZUBI.GPS_TRACKER_DATA as
                         select * from KAKATEL.GPS_POSITION';
  end case;
end;
/
```